# SimpleInjector injects an empty collection when using a generic interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm trying to implement a similar scenario of `CompositeValidator` in the Simple Injector [docs](https://simpleinjector.org/advanced#batch-registration).

Here is the composite class:

```
public class CompositePriceCalculator<T> : IPriceCalculator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IPriceCalculator<T>> _priceCalculators;

    public CompositePriceCalculator(IEnumerable<IPriceCalculator<T>> priceCalculators)
    {
        this._priceCalculators = priceCalculators;
    }

    public double CalculatePrice(T item)
    {
       var totalPrice = _priceCalculators.Sum(priceCalc => priceCalc.CalculatePrice(item));
       return totalPrice;
    }
}
```

Some implementation of `IPriceCalculator`:

```
public class Class1 : IPriceCalculator<SomeModel>
{
    public double CalculatePrice(SomeModel item) => ...
}
```

Registration:

```
container.Collection.Register(typeof(IPriceCalculator<>), new [] { typeof(Class1) });
container.Register(typeof(IPriceCalculator<>), typeof(CompositePriceCalculator<>),
                Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

For some reason, when entering `CalculatePrice` method in `CompositePriceCalculator` class - `_priceCalculators` collection is empty (Count = 0).

Can someone assist why `Class1` does not inject into `IEnumerable<IPriceCalculator<T>>` collection ?

**UPDATE**

Suppose `SomeModel` inherit from `BaseModel`

```
public class SomeModel : BaseModel
{
}
```

`Class1` implements `IPriceCalculator<BaseModel>` BUT need `SomeModel` for its implementation.

```
public class Class1 : IPriceCalculator<BaseModel>
{
    public double CalculatePrice(BaseModel item)
    {
        var someModel = item as SomeModel;
        // Uses someModel
    }
}
```

Any class that wants to `CalculatePrice` implements `IPriceCalculator` with `BaseModel` in order for `CompositePriceCalculator` to iterate all of those `IPriceCalculator<BaseModel>` instances.

```
public class Class2 : IPriceCalculator<BaseModel>
{
    public double CalculatePrice(BaseModel item)
    {
        var someModel2 = item as SomeModel2;
        // Uses someModel2
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to design the code in such way to avoid casting to `SomeModel` in `Class1` but still get the iteration on all IPriceCalculators ?

Comment: You mean "inject into `IEnumerable<IPriceCalculator<SomeModel>>`"?

Comment: Class1 is only injected into a `CompositePriceCalculator<SomeModel>`. Please show an MCVE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @ric.net I expected that Class1 instance would be inside _priceCalculators collection

Comment: @Steven according to SimpleInjector docs, I think that there should be a way to register the container that Class1 instance would be a part of _priceCalculators collection instance.

Comment: Please show an MCVE.

Comment: @Steven this is MCVE. I can't minimize it anymore.

Comment: Minimal, but not complete. Please show the scenario whete the collection is empty where you expect it to have one. Preferably, show a small example that can be copy-pasted and run as is, e.g. as a console application. Only this way we can verify what you are doing.

Comment: @Steven as mentioned, I expect _priceCalculators collection in the first class would have one. Because dealing with DI with various classes - I can't minimize it to a small paste & run example.

Comment: But what is exact type of `CompositePriceCalculator<T>` are you resolving (i.e. what is `T`) where you are seeing 0 elements where you expect 1?

Comment: Ans to be sure you are not hitting some obscure bug, are you using the latest version of Simple Injector?

Comment: @Steven T can be any type. I followed the SimpleInjector composite example in the link I provided.
During debug CompositePriceCalculator<T> i'm getting an empty _priceCalculators collection. I'm using SimpleInjector 4.4.2 .

Comment: But that's the whole issue here. While `T` can be any type, `Class1` will only be injected in case `T` is a `SomeModel`. So with which `T` did you test this?

Comment: @Steven I expect that any class that implements IPriceCalculator<> would be placed in _priceCalculators.
For instance: 
Class1 : IPriceCalculator<SomeModel>
Class2: IPriceCalculator<SomeModel2>
Class3: IPriceCalculator<SomeModel3>

I expect all of those to be part of _priceCalculators.
This is according to SimpleInjector collection registration docs:
https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html?#batch-registration

Comment: I understood from the docs that the whole point of CompositeValidator is that this class would get all IEnumerable<IValidator<T>> implementations, iterate on them and execute some method.

Comment: Simple Injector won't do magic. It can't inject `Class1` into a `CompositePriceCalculator<SomeModel2>`. Please try to construct such object graph by hand in C#. You'll notice that this won't compile. Hence, that's why Simple Injector will automatically filter out incompatible types on your behalf.

Comment: @Steven and what if SomeModel, SomeModel2, SomeModel3 would all inherit from BasicModel ?

Comment: That *could* work, but only if you defined the `IPriceCalculator<T>` as a contravariant interface, but in that case, you will get base type implementations injected into a `Composite<SubType>` but not the other way around. But again: experiment with this by hand-constructing these graphs in C#. The compiler will show you the limitations that Simple Injector has to obey to.

Comment: @Steven can you help me a bit further more ? Is there any design issue with casting an entity type ? I think that Composite  will get the IEnumerable<IPriceCalculator<BaseModel>> and Class1 would implement IPriceCalculator<BaseModel> . Unfortunately, this would involve casting from BaseModel to SomeModel in Class1. Is there any way to avoid it without using "dynamic" type ?

Comment: I'll bw glad to help you. Could you update your question and add code that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve? Nothing paints a clearer picture than code. I'd expect to see how the calculator is used, perhaps one or two simple calculator implementations, the definition of the calculator interface. Do note that I'm AFK ATM (as I'm writing this on my phone), so it might take some time for me to post a full answer.

Comment: @Steven Thanks. I have updated my question.

Comment: Hi @ohadinho, please add some examples of how `IPriceCalculator<T>` is _consumed_. Do consumers regularly have to calculate prices for (many) different models, or does a consumer typically only need one type of model to get prices calculated? Please show that in code.

Comment: @Steven Yes. The whole point is to use different models. As I wrote in the comment "Uses someModel" where someModel is after casting and uses some specific properties in SomeModel that does not exist in BaseModel.

Comment: I would like to see how a consumer of `IPriceCalculator<T>` is using it. This allows me to better understand your needs and how to best design the application. If you add that information, I will be able to supply you with an answer that describes an alternative design.